# switch не считывает строки

Tags: java

Добрый день, у меня возникла проблема с incompatible types error, проблема заключается в том что switch не считывает строки, хотя версия jdk 9

```
private void gameProcess() {
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(nameOfPlayer + ", тебе брошено испытание! Докажи, что ты крут :)");
    while (!isWin) {
        showMaze();
        String step = userInput();

        boolean isSetPositionDone = false;
        switch (step) {
            case UP:
                isSetPositionDone = setPlayerPosition(0, -1);
                break;
            case DOWN:
                isSetPositionDone = setPlayerPosition(0, 1);
                break;
            case LEFT:
                isSetPositionDone = setPlayerPosition(-1, 0);
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                isSetPositionDone = setPlayerPosition(1, 0);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Юзер мега-долбадятел");
                break;
        }

        if (!isSetPositionDone)
            System.out.println("Вы не можете туда пойти!");

        abstactClear();
    }

    // Когда мы наконец-то выйграли
    win();
}

// Метод для пользовательского ввода
private String userInput() {
    String answer = "";

    do {
        System.out.println("Куда игроку пойти: w - вверх, s - вниз, a - влево, d - вправо");
        System.out.print("Ход: ");
        answer = scanner.next();

        // Приводим к нижнему регистру
        answer = answer.toLowerCase();
    }
    while (!(answer.equals(UP) || answer.equals(DOWN) ||
            answer.equals(LEFT) || answer.equals(RIGHT)));

    return answer;
}
```

Comment: Добавьте к вопросу полный текст ошибки.

Answer (score 3):

Я , конечно, не экстрасенс, но мне кажется, что ошибка заключается в сравнении с LEFT, RIGHT, DOWN, UP. у вас это случаем не Enum? Если да, то Enum нужно сравнивать с Enum либо переопределить в Enum метод toString и сравнивать стринги, первый вариант предпочтительней, иначе смысл от Enum никакого.